# Conditioning behaviour of a macro on whether on top of a new page

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals

Is there a way to find out, whether the currently typeset material will go to top of a page?

I am trying to write a macro which, when invoked, typesets a horizontal divider to separate the subsequent content from the preceding one. However, if the subsequent content goes to top of the next page, the horizontal divider should be suppressed. How could I do that?

I am aware `\pagetotal` and `\thepage` are not the way to go (the page-breaking algorithm often decides where to put the break when the material is already typeset and my macro has been invoked).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TeX provides a very useful but relatively little employed way to typeset horizontal rules depending on whether or not they happen to be the last element in the textblock on the page. That's to incorporate your rule within vertical glue (recall that TeX ordinarily ignores final vertical glues in textblocks). Calling on one of the `\leaders` family of commands should get you where you want. E.g., using `\cleaders`, you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\divider}{%
  \medskip%
  \cleaders\vbox to 0.4pt{\hrule width\linewidth}\vskip0.4pt%
  \medskip%
}

\newcommand{\text}{
  I am trying to write a macro which, when invoked, typesets a
  horizontal divider to separate the subsequent content from
  the preceding one.\par\divider}

\begin{document}
\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text
\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text
\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text\text
That's all!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code is doing? It looks like the `vbox` nudges things up, and then the `vskip` nudges them back again. This seems like the net effect should be nil. But it isn't, so there's something I haven't understood. (I think it would be nice if answers did more than just solve the problem, but also taught people about TeX and friends...

Comment: The `\cleaders` takes a box and a space argument, and places as many copies of the box it needs to fill the space. It can be used both in vertical and horizontal mode. Here the box is a vertical box with a height of 0.4pt, and the space is also a vertical space of 0.4pt so the box will be used once to fill the space. So there is no nudging back and forth. The point is that the box with the rule is within vertical glue, and does not have the status as a text box, so it will be ignored at the end of the page.

Comment: @Jørgen: You can't comment at a different question or answer until you get 50rep points. This is in force to prevent harm by spam-bots etc. I converted it to a comment for you.

Comment: @Martin: how's he supposed to get rep if you go and convert his answers to comments, huh? :-P

Comment: @SamB: His "answer" started with "This is really a comment to the comment to Geoffrey Jones' answer, but I couldn't figure out how to do that, so it's posted as an answer.", so I didn't had much hesitation to convert it.

Comment: Interestingly, I was wondering if it were possible to do almost the exact opposite for thought breaks the other day. That is, to use some ink (perhaps a rule, perhaps something a bit more complicated) *only* at page breaks, and otherwise just use some vertical whitespace. And I even thought of this sort of leader trick, which unfortunately won't work because they disappear just when I would *want* the ink... too bad there's no `\discretionary` in vertical mode! (Though it turns out that you can't use glue inside that anyway, which would be kind of bad in vertical mode...)

Comment: By the way, this approach does not work if ``\text`` is ``longtable`` (probably because of the interference of hacks, as usual). Is there some other solution?