# Condition to determine if current line ends or starts the page

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditioning behaviour of a macro on whether on top of a new page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6443/conditioning-behaviour-of-a-macro-on-whether-on-top-of-a-new-page)

I have two paragraphs with some separator (rule) between them. I want to make this separator appear only if it does not end or start the page (in which case it is just redundant). Is there some package with conditionals I can use? In pseudocode, I need something like this:

```
\if (less than \baselineskip till the end of page)
    \pagebreak
\else \if (page just started)
    % do nothing
\else
    \rule
\fi
```

The package `needspace` provides functionality close to the first conditional, but it does not export any conditionals, and, unfortunately, I am not that good in TeX to extract them from package myself.

Comment: I think [Conditioning behaviour of a macro on whether on top of a new page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6443/conditioning-behaviour-of-a-macro-on-whether-on-top-of-a-new-page) is what you need.

Comment: Please take a look at the question that Caramdir havs suggested as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.