# Suppress something if at the end or beginning of a page

Tags: formatting, page-breaking

I would like to suppress the horizontal rule between the `mdframed` boxes if it occurs at the top or bottom of a page.

I found [this partial solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6444/14757) which makes use of `\cleaders`. But it is nor working.

See my 3 pages:

[image]

I'm using `\par\cleaders\vbox to 0.4pt{\hrule width\linewidth}\vskip0.4pt` after `\end{mdframed}` and so on page 1 there are 3 of them. But I'd like only 2 between those 3 boxes.

### Minimal code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nobreak]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\divider}{%
\vspace{2ex}
\par\cleaders\vbox to 0.4pt{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}\vskip0.4pt%
\vspace{2ex}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You have to put glues that cancel each other before the leaders and also a penalty for making a break preferable between those glue; this is the object of the macro `\filbreak`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nobreak]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\divider}{%
  \par
  \filbreak
  \xleaders\vbox to 4ex{\vfill\hrule width\hsize height1pt\vfill}\vskip4ex
}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[3]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\divider

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want only finite glue instead of infinite glue, if something else follows

```
\newcommand{\divider}{%
  \par
  \vskip0pt plus 40pt\penalty-200\vskip0pt plus-40pt
  \xleaders\vbox to 4ex{\vfill\hrule width\hsize height1pt\vfill}\vskip4ex
}
```

Comment: Dear @egreg, tell me if I'm wrong: `\vbox to 4ex{}` creates a vertical box with height `4ex`; inside it we put `\vfill\hrule width\hsize height1pt\vfill` to vertical center the horizontal rule; finally `\vskip4ex` moves the current position to the bottom of the vertical box (this is the reason to use the same value `4ex`).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to understand the difference between the `\divider` commands. The second one is better *if something else follows*? Follows what? The `\divider`?

Comment: @Sigur Do you have text after the last `\divider` command?

Comment: no. But I'd like to remove the rule after the last abstract. It's ugly to see it. lol

Comment: @Sigur Remove the last `\divider` command! If it's part of the definition of an environment, it could be more complicated. The `\vskip 4ex` after the `\vbox` is the glue specification for `\xleaders`, it's requested by the syntax.

Comment: You're right, as always. I'm using a command to insert the abstracts inside the framed box followed by the divider. So I just type `\newabstract{01}\newabstract{02}\newabstract{03}`. I guess that I'll define a starred version without the divider to be used at the end.

Comment: I'd set the divider *before* the abstract; you can add a conditional that is false at the first abstract and true after it, so that the divider is not added the first time.