# Placement of rules at the top or bottom of a page

Tags: typography, rules

I am writing a two-column document and I use `\hrule` to separate different sections. Once the `\hrule` reaches the top or the bottom of the page it stays there. Shouldn't for aesthetic reasons be placed elsewhere so to have text above and below it? Tex shouldn't take this for account so to place the rules accordingly? I don't know if this the right thing to do when someone typesets a document but that's how it seems to me. Am I wrong?

I don't want to change something in my document so I don't want a solution for the code or another solution. My question's purpose is what is the right thing to do when trying to typeset a document like that? You should leave a rule at the top or the bottom of the page or you should try to fix it because of a typesetting aesthetic "rule"? Moreover TeX shouldn't do something for it (if that is indeed wrong), like when we have an underful or overful box that gives warning ?

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you tell TeX that it should go *here*, then TeX will put it *here*. Could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: TeX doesn't make aesthetic judgements, it does what you tell it, you can have the rule disappear at a page break or strongly discourage breaks at a rule but you have to tell it what you want.

Comment: The issue doesn't stem from a specific example but it is like a general question regarding typesetting and aesthetics. I will upload an image in case it helps.

Comment: You should always include a complete small document that demonstrates the effect (if you want people to test their answers)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle TeX isn't about beautiful documents? It breaks sentences so to have documents without text overflow and many other modification so the output to be beautiful. My question is in the same spirit.

Comment: To make this clear I am not looking for a code solution but rather an insight whether the algorithms of TeX take something like that into account or if they should.

Comment: @Adam TeX doesn't rewrite text to improve linebreaks and it won't linebreak at all if you put the entire paragraph in a `\mbox` You have given no indication of what you want to happen (rule to go or pagebreak to happen somewhere else) and given no indication of the markup. If you said what you wanted to happen and what markup you used, someone could suggest how to change your markup. As it is I think the question should be closed as "unclear"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you may be right I will modify my question.

Comment: This could help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154248/14757

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX just follows instructions. Your question isn't really answerable, all you have shown is an image of some output that you don't want, so the solution is to change the markup, but you have given no indication of that. In comments you suggest it is like line breaking, but if you post a long line and ask why it doesn't break, it could be that you used `~` instead of spaces, or that the text is in an `\mbox` or it is in the wrong language hyphenation has been set up. You have just shown a horizontal line, it is there because the macros specify that it should be there, if you specified something else, TeX would do something else.

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textheight{-30\baselineskip}
\def\a{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve. }
\def\b{Red. \a Blue green \a\a Yellow \a}

\begin{document}


\b\b\b

\b\a

\bigskip

\hrule
\section{zzz}

\b\b

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If you tell TeX not to break before a rule by changing the document to look like

```
\nopagebreak% added this line
\bigskip

\hrule
```

Then TeX adjusts the page breaking and you get

[image]

If instead you tell it the rule is discardable and change the markup to

```
\bigskip

\leaders \hrule \vskip0.4pt
\section{zzz}
```

Then normally you would get a rule, but at a page break it would be discarded just as white space above a heading is discarded at a break, and you get

[image]

Comment: What does `\leaders` do exactly?

Comment: @cfr it normally makes the dots in a table of contents:-) but it acts like _glue_ here acting like `vskip 4pt` and in particular it is discarded at a break, but instead of white space it puts the specified box or rule

Comment: Thank you. That's good to know. (Until I forget then it would be good to know.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you very much. As I had mentioned I wasn't looking for a solution to something so that's why I didn't upload a MWE because my question didn't originate from a specific document. Your answer is very helpful for future reference. Can I ask one thing though? You mentioned previously "TeX doesn't make aesthetic judgements, it does what you tell it". What did you mean by that? I thought that was one of the purposes of TeX to create the perfect document.

Comment: @Adam I basically meant what I said in this answer. TeX is just a computer program that follows instructions, it lays out text according to some constraints and the intention is that you specify constraints that lead to typographically good documents, but it doesn't judge you; if you specify a rule to go at the top of the page it doesn't object, it just does what you say. So given an image of a rule at the top of the page, which is all you provide, there is not much really that can be said about TeX's algorithms.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thank you very much your answer is very appreciated!